# Function to alphabetically sort custom post types creating duplicates

Tags: functions, sort

I have a function that creates a list of custom post types and sorts them alphabetically. It also takes the first letter of those posts and shows it as a header. For some reason, at some point it stops adding posts to the letter F for example and it moves on, to then create another F and add the remaining posts there instead of adding all of the posts together, I'm really clueless as to why that happens. Here is the function:

```
function alfabetic_order( $cat_n = "")
{ 


    if(isset($_REQUEST['post_type'])) {

        global $query_string;
    $args=($query_string.'&taxonomy=type&term='.$cat_n.'&orderby=name&order=ASC&post_status=publish' );
    $new_empresas = get_posts( $args);
    } else {
            $args = array('post_type' => 'las-empresas',
                'taxonomy' => 'type',
                'term' => $cat_n,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC',
            );
            $new_empresas = get_posts( $args);
    }
    //  echo "maulik".$cat_n;
    //}
    $i = 1;
    $l = 0;
    $html .= '<div class="tabs-section">';
    foreach ($new_empresas as $empresas) {

        $this_char = strtoupper(mb_substr($empresas->post_title, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'));
        if ($this_char != $last_char) {
            if ($last_char != '') {
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '</div>';

            }

            $last_char = $this_char;
            if ($l % 3 == 0) {
                $html .= '</div><div class="tabs-section">';
            }
            $l++;

            $html .= '<div class="bx-section fadeInIn-Big">';
            $html .= '<h1>' . $last_char . '</h1>';
            $html .= '<div class="ctn-section">';
            $html .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($empresas->ID) . '">' . $empresas->post_title . '</a>';
        } else {
            $html .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($empresas->ID) . '">' . $empresas->post_title . '</a>';
        }

        $i++;

    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';


    return $html;

}
```

Here is the HTMl that calls it in the template:

```
 <div id="tabs-1">
                    <?php //echo $html;
                    echo  alfabetic_order( $cat_name="") ?>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-2">
                    <?php echo  alfabetic_order( $cat_name="empresas") ?>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-3">                    
                    <?php echo  alfabetic_order( $cat_name="centros-educativos") ?>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-4">                    
                    <?php echo  alfabetic_order( $cat_name="asociaciones-empresariales") ?>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-5">                    
                    <?php echo  alfabetic_order( $cat_name="instituciones") ?>

                </div>
```

And the page in question, the problem is very obvious:

http://www.alianzafpdual.es/miembros/instituciones/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'orderby' => 'name'` sorts by slug - not title;
therefore, the title **Imancorp Foundation** which has this permalink **http://www.alianzafpdual.es/las-empresas/fundacion-imancorp-foundation**/ breaks the list.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

try and use instead `'orderby' => 'title'`

Comment: You are a lifesaver, that fixed it. Thank you very much.